# Getting a javascript error "Object doesn't support property or method 'get'" when selecting option in grouped kendo dropdown for grid editor

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-dropdown

I'm trying to create a kendo dropdown with grouping for a custom editor to a field in a kendo grid. When the editor is used the dropdown is populated successfully with grouping, however selecting any option throws the javascript error "Object doesn't support property or method 'get'".

Relevant code is below:

Editor Function:

```
function productDropDownEditor(container, options) {
    $('<input required name="' + options.field + '"/>')
                .appendTo(container)
                .kendoDropDownList({
                    autoBind: false,
                    dataTextField: "Name",
                    dataValueField: "Product_ID",
                    dataSource: {
                        transport: {
                            type: "json",
                            read: {
                                url: "http://localhost/Application/GetProducts",
                                dataType: "json",
                                type: "POST"
                            }
                        },
                        group: { field: "Category" }
                    }
                });
}
```

Note that the datasource is simply retrieving a JSON object from an MVC service. An example of what it would retrieve can be seen below:

```
[{Product_ID: "1", Category: "Food", Name:"Maple Syrup"}, {Product_ID: "1", Category: "Sports", Name:"Hockey Sticks"}]
```

For reference, below is the grid that calls the update editor template:

```
var testSuiteGrid = $("#productsGrid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: {
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: http://localhost/Application/GetStoreProducts,
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST"
            },
            update: {
                url: http://localhost/Application/UpdateStoreProducts,
                datatype: "json",
                type: "POST",
                complete: function (e) {
                    productGrid.data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read();
                }
            },
            create: {
                url: http://localhost/Application/AddStoreProducts,
                dataType: "json",
                data: {
                },
                type: "POST",
                complete: function (e) {
                    productGrid.data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read();
                }
            },
            destroy: {
                url: http://localhost/Application/RemoveStoreProducts,
                dataType: "json",
                data: {
                },
                type: "POST",
                complete: function (e) {
                    productGrid.data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read();
                }
            }
        }
    },
    toolbar: ["create"],
    editable: {
        createAt: "bottom",
        mode: "inline"
    },
    columns: [
        { field: "Product_ID" },
        { field: "Product_Description" },
        { field: "Product_ID", title: "Product", editor: productDropDownEditor, template: "#=ProductName#" },
        { command: ["edit", "destroy"] }
    ],
    resizable: true,
    scrollable: false
});
```

Comment: I created a dojo from the code you provided(with a hardcoded array as the data for the datasource as I don't have access to your urls) and a couple tweaks to correct the second "Product_ID" column definition(assume it should be "Name"):  http://dojo.telerik.com/@Stephen/oTaSI and it kind of appears to be working...can you duplicate your issue using the dojo as a starting point?

Comment: Thanks for taking a look, I looked at your dojo and I've realized I may have oversimplified my issue when I created the example above as mine is not just a template field with one field, but an aggregation of several which could potentially complicate things. I'll amend my example to illustrate it better.